# Mass spectrum analysis

Tags: analytical-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

When finding ions which correspond to certain fragments on a mass spectrum; there are multiple possible ions that can correspond to the same fragment;
How should I know which one is the correct one?

Comment: see if you can get your sample onto a Time of Flight - Reflectron spectrometer  as this will have superior mass resolution.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking: knowing the history of your sample (e.g. earlier steps of synthesis allowing / excluding elements that could numerically fit into the list of suggested fragments) and additional spectroscopic characterisation (UV-Vis, IR, Raman, NMR, etc.) may be helpful.

The problem you describe may be *attenuated* by using a mass spectrometer of higher [resolving power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(mass_spectrometry)).  Instead of submitting the sample to the detector behind a smaller LC-MS coupled analysis, providing a purified sample to a larger, tuneable [sector mass spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sector_mass_spectrometer), for example.

An important alternative is coupling of several mass spectrometers along one line, where after initial ionisation *primary* fragments are separated from each other, and their corresponding subsequently generated daughter fragments are eventually characterised, like in a tandem MS/MS:

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_mass_spectrometry))

An overview about the later provides this [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_mass_spectrometry).